# Set VBA Range with Variable End

Tags: excel, vba

I'm kind of new to VBA and am struggling to understand some of the syntax.

I have a range from `a3:c13`, for example, and I'd like to set it as a variable so I can pass it to vlookup later as a the table array. However, the range is defined by user input in terms of its size. It will always start in `A3`, it will always include columns `A:C`, but I don't know how far down it would go. In that case, I think I'd set it as:

```
With range("a3")
    table_array = range(.cells(0,0), .End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)).Select
End With
```

However, that doesn't seem to work. I get a runtime error:

`Run-time Error '1004': Method '_Default' of object 'Range' failed.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming cols A, B, and C have the same number of rows:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Set r = Range("A3")
    Set table_array = Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Resize(, 3)
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome, quick and concise!

Answer (score 0):

You can find the last row in Col A:C and then construct your range?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Rng As Range

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            LastRow = .Range("A:C").Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            LastRow = 1
        End If

        If Not LastRow < 3 Then
            Set Rng = .Range("A3:C" & LastRow)

            Debug.Print Rng.Address
        Else
            MsgBox "No Data found beyond A3"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```